# When does std::as_writable_bytes trigger undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

I thought I finally understood `reinterpret_cast` and strict aliasing, and then I came across this example, slightly modified from the "Invalid scalar" example on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

https://godbolt.org/z/navGM37h3

```cpp
#include <span>

int g() {
    bool b[1] = {true};
    std::span<bool> bs(b);

    auto ps = std::as_writable_bytes(bs);
    ps[0] = std::byte{10};

    return b[0] == 0;
}

int h() {
    bool b{true};
    std::span<bool> bs(&b, 1);

    auto ps = std::as_writable_bytes(bs);
    ps[0] = std::byte{10};

    return b == 0;
}
```

From the godbolt link I can see that the `g` function gives the assembly output I expect, and the `h` does not. I have also understood that the lifetime of `b` in the `h` function ends when I write to it from the byte pointer (similar to how unions work), causing undefined behavior. I also think the `g` function is similar to the example for as_bytes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes

My question then is:

Is the `g` function free from undefined behavior? Why/why not?

and possible follow up questions:

If `g` has the same problem as the `h` function, what is the purpose of `std::as_writable_bytes` and how do you use it in a correct way? Is it instead illegal to create a span over a non-array element? Is any of this only specific to bool (my testing seems to suggest so, but always hard to tell with undefined behavior)?

Comment: Both are equally UB. `as_writable_bytes` is a red herring, it's just a glorified `reinterpret_cast<char *>`. It's useful in the same scenarios as `reinterpret_cast<char *>`, e.g. deserializing binary data. `bool` is just not designed to be deserialized this way, due to having invalid bit patterns.

Comment: `sizeof(bool)` is also sus, it should be 1, as you have one `bool`. It doesn't obviously break because on your platform `sizeof(bool)` *is* 1

Comment: `as_writable_bytes` is introduced because the meaning of `reinterpret_cast` is too badly overloaded. It is introduced as an alternative spelling to express the intention more clearly. It is not introduced to sidestep UBs by `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @caleth: I fixed the sizeof(bool), and changed `b[0] == 0` in `g'. My thinking around the question is that the `as_bytes` function does not have any UB from what I undertand (since you are always allowed to read bytes via a std::byte pointer), so then why was the as_writable_bytes added?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, do you think there is UB in the example for `as_bytes` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes meaning the UB comes from the invalid bit patterns in `bool`, and if used with `int` instead there is no UB (and UB is not related to the aliasing issues from `reinterpret_cast`)?

Comment: Yep, no UB in that snippet. Would be fine with an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`b == 0` in `g()` is asking if `b == nullptr` since `b` is an array (which the compiler optimizes to `false`).

Also your function `h()` should have `std::span<bool> bs(&b, 1)` since you only have 1 bool.

Your first function as it is currently written is free from UB, since writing to `b` might make it have a trap representation but you never actually try to read from it.

But changing it to `return b[0] == false;` will make it have the same UB as the second function.

As for your follow up question, you have to write a valid object representation:

```cpp
int h() {
    bool b{true};
    std::span<bool> bs(&b, 1);

    auto ps = std::as_writable_bytes(bs);

    bool f{false};
    std::span<bool> fs(&f, 1);
    std::ranges::copy(std::as_bytes(fs), ps.begin());

    return b == false;
}
```

Comment: I've corrected the question with the code changes you suggested. Regarding *you have to write a valid object representation*, is this related to bool, i.e. if I write `byte{1}` instead of `byte{10}` (or as in your example copy from another bool), will this remove the UB?